# WorkManager cannot find required zero-argument constructor

Tags: java, android, android-workmanager

I'm using `WorkManager` `1.0.0-alpha02` found in the `android.arch.work:work-runtime` dependency to query a web page every one minute (the querying code is excluded for this example as it's irrelevant).

When I use `WorkManager` like this:

```
WorkManager
                .getInstance()
                .enqueue(
                        new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                                MessageWorker.class,
                                1,
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES
                        )
                                .setConstraints(
                                        new Constraints.Builder()
                                                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                                                .build()
                                )
                                .build()
                );

private class MessageWorker extends Worker {
        public MessageWorker() {
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public WorkerResult doWork() {
            // Do stuff
            return WorkerResult.SUCCESS;
        }
}
```

it gives this error message:

```
05-31 17:50:05.645 11749-12168/com.neelkamath.webview E/WorkerWrapper: Trouble instantiating com.neelkamath.webview.MainActivity$MessageWorker
    java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.neelkamath.webview.MainActivity$MessageWorker> has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.workerFromClassName(WorkerWrapper.java:405)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.workerFromWorkSpec(WorkerWrapper.java:377)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:132)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
05-31 17:50:05.645 11749-12168/com.neelkamath.webview E/WorkerWrapper: Could for create Worker com.neelkamath.webview.MainActivity$MessageWorker
```

I have tried the following constructors to no avail:

- no constructor
- public
- private
- constructor with a non-empty body with the only statement as `super();`

Comment: Have you tried making the MessageWorker class not private?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove following constructor from MessageWorker and make the class `public`. :

```
public MessageWorker() {
}
```

Also ensure class is in separate file.

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear enough, I've tried editing it now to clarify. I have tried running it without the constructor as well, but it did not work.

Comment: @Neel when you say `public` did you try to make class public? Try to place the Worker in individual file and make it publicly accessible.

Comment: taking it in a separate class did it! It seems to be like a sort of BroadcastReciever in my use case.

Comment: great! enjoy coding

Answer (score 1):

You can create the MessageWorker class in separate file, and if you want to make MessageWorker class as nested class, you can also make it `static`:

```
public static class MessageWorker extends Worker {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public WorkerResult doWork() {
        // Do stuff
        return WorkerResult.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

The reason is the WorkerWrapper will create your worker instance by `clazz.newInstance()`, and there is no zero argument constructor for nested class